# Project Euler problem #3 (how to do it by hand?)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, project-euler

Problem #3 in Project Euler:

> What is the largest prime factor of the number $600851475143$?

I want to solve this by hand. (I am doing this with all problems.) What techniques would allow me to figure this out? (Yes, I checked the prime factors up to $53$, but I got quite tired.)

Comment: But... why? Why would you take problems meant to be done with a computer program and do them by hand?

Comment: Well, since $N\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ you know there have to be prime factors of the form $p=4k+3$.  That sort of helps.  As it happens, there is a prime factor of that form just a bit greater than where you stopped....but that's just good fortune.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, I think it's a bad idea to have the straight up answer here. I'm actually working on the third Euler problem, and I was curious about how you'd do it by hand. Otherwise, though, the site specifically asks that you don't share the answer!

Comment: @heather: that answer is at hand of anyone, due to WA. And I do not understand what is the purpose of finding the factorization of that number by hand.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio the idea is that I want *techniques* that would enable me to do this in a reasonable time by hand

Comment: @Cauchy: then open Wikipedia and study factorization algorithms like the quadratic sieve and primality testing like Lucas-Lehmer and Miller-Rabin. Bad idea to implement them by hand, anyway.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, true, but that's beside the point. Sure, someone could find out using Wolfram Alpha. But that's out of our control. Let's take care of what's in our control. Secondly, as Cauchy said, techniques are the point here, not the answer.

Comment: @heather: then the question is just too broad. Should we describe any factorization or primality testing algorithm in a supposed answer?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, I don't think it's too broad. Don't describe every primality/factorization testing algorithm in existence, but rather, describe ones that are easy to carry out by hand and quick (for example).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The question asks for a method which can lead to success in reasonable time without a computer. Probably the answer should include at least one method which solves this particular problem.

Comment: @heather: I doubt there is some cheap way to deduce that 6857 is a prime factor, or that 6857 is a prime number. But an interesting fact is that the representation in base $23$ of $600851475143$ is $$7\color{red}{fail}8hi3 $$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio how did you figure this out?!

Comment: @Cauchy: I was trying to figure if our number can be represented in a compact way with respect to some base, trying to reproduce something similar to Euler's proof that $641$ is a divisor of the fifth Fermat number (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number)

Comment: Divide $600851475143$ by every neighbor of a multiple of $6$ (starting from $5$), until you find a factor. Then divide $600851475143$ by this factor. Then do the same for the result.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're bored, you might try this:  Multiply the first few primes together and call it $M$.  Then compute the gcd of $M$ and your number by Euclidean algorithm.  Since your number has about 12 digits, use enough primes so that $M$ is 14 or 15 digits.  By Lame's theorem, this should take at most 5 times 12 = 60 steps.  If the gcd turns out to be different from 1, you've found a factor.  If not, then make a new $M$ of 14 or 15 digits by multiplying the next few primes together and repeat.

If I were really doing this by hand, I think I'd make $M$ as large as I could stand (maybe 50 digits), because after the first step in Euclidean algorithm, both numbers would be less than 12 digits.  So I could eliminate a lot of candidates at once, at the price of one horrendous long division.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost: there is no known fast general-case algorithm for factorization (that's the reason RSA encryption exists). Any hope you might have to solve the problem by hand lies in making some lucky guess.

**Guess 1 (not lucky):** suppose for our $N$, $N=ab$, $|a-b|$ is small. Then we have: $$N = ab = ({a+b \over 2})^2 - ({a-b \over 2})^2 \\
(\lceil \sqrt N \rceil + \delta)^2 - N = m^2$$
where $\delta$ is some small natural number. Testing $\delta$ from $0$ to $10$ fails in our case.

**Guess 2 (lucky, but cheating):** the method above also works for $pN$ where $p$ is odd. Let $p=55$, then $\lceil \sqrt {pN} \rceil = 5748638$, $(\lceil \sqrt {pN} \rceil + 1)^2 - pN = 19219456 = 4384^2$.